# notify callback on angular promise is never called when using a custom method

Tags: angularjs, callback, promise, decorator, notify

I've got a decorator adding a **promise.progress(callback)** method to promises to launch a callback when a **promise.notify()** is made:

```
  angular
  .module('myApi', [])
  .config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$q', function ($delegate) {
      var defer = $delegate.defer;
      $delegate.defer = function () {
        var deferred = defer();
        Object.getPrototypeOf(deferred.promise).progress = function(callback) { 
          return deferred.promise.then(null, null, callback);
        }
        return deferred;
      };
      return $delegate;
    });
  });
```

Doing `get("/myUrl").then(callback1, callback2, callback3);` works fine and callback3 is called everytime there is a notify (with an angular.noop to force angular to schedule the notification). But when I do it with the extra method then it doesn't work:

```
  get("/myUrl")
  .then(callback1)
  .catch(callback2)
  .progress(callback3);
```

There are no output errors. Everything works "fine", it's just that callback3 is never called. Since angular defines .catch as just returning a promise with .then(null, callback) I thought about doing the same on my decorator, but I guess something more is needed.

If my decorator is fine and the error is somewhere else I can put all related code, just ask.

Comment: version of angular?

Comment: 1.4.9, bit old, but can't upgrade.

Comment: why progress method and not just use finally?

Comment: Modularity. Finally clause is a 2 callback method (callback, progressBack) and my idea is to have just one callback as .catch() does. I also could use .then(cb1, cb2, cb3) as I'm doing now but well... I'm stubborn.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Don't know exactly why but this works:

```
  angular
  .module('myApi', []).config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$q', function ($delegate) {
      var defer = $delegate.defer;
      $delegate.defer = function () {
        var deferred = defer();
        Object.getPrototypeOf(deferred.promise).progress = function(callback) {
          return this.then(null, null, callback);
        }
        return deferred;
      };
      return $delegate;
    });
  });
```

On debugger, both codes show exactly the same result. But this one works, original doesn't.